# Starting a Lexus that has been sitting and has a good battery

Tags: starting, car, lexus

I have tested the battery and it is okay. The issue is that when I turn the key I get no electrical response. We used the car last Thanksgiving. Does the car shut down something else when it is idle for so long? What should I check?

Comment: When you say you tested the battery, what was the voltage?

Comment: It would be helpful to know *how* you tested the battery. A malfunctioning battery could show enough voltage until you turn the key and put a load on it.

Answer (score 1):

I would take the clamps off of the battery posts, clean them, then re-cinch them down. I would bet one or both of them has lost connectivity either through some light oxidation or whatever. If you aren't getting *any* connection and no power to any part of the car, there has to be an issue with getting power to those bits and pieces.